# How to write the Fibonacci sequence using array type inside a library in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, fibonacci

I am writing a library featuring several common mathematical methods as a way to hone my skills. I am trying to implement the Fibonacci sequence using arrays. Here is the code in the library:

```
     public static int[] Fibonacci(int numElement)
     {
        int n = numElement - 1;
        int[] a = new int[numElement + 1];
        a[0] = 0;
        a[1] = 1;



        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        {
            a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];

        }

      return a;

    }
}
```

To test it I used a console application in which I referenced my dll:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] b = new int[9];
        b = numberTheory.Fibonacci(9);
        foreach (var item in b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is the output of the above code (9 for input):

0

1

1

0

0

0

0

0

0

Any other input results in the same output *format*. How can I fix my code to get the desired output?

**EDIT** : it seems that the loop does not iterate irrespective of the position of return statement (or its existence at all).

Comment: You're returning within the loop, so after the first iteration, so only the first three elements will be touched. Use breakpoints and use the debugger to follow your program flow.

Comment: @P.basimfar Just remove the return line from the For loop in Fibonacci function then it should work fine.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code and see what's wrong.

Comment: @BalrajSingh Removing the return statement also does not work. Same output

Comment: I edited the code to show that I cannot get the correct answer even if the return statement is out of the for loop. If you notice the inconsistency of answers that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning prematurely and the wrong type - as pointed by @konked. However the solution provided by him, still has a problem: Fibonacci(9) should be equal to 34 (not 21). So you will need n+1 places in the array.

```
public int[] Fibonacci(int numElement)
{
     if (numElement < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("numElement", numElement, "Fibonnaci number to get must be greater or equal than 0");

        var n = numElement + 1; //you need n+1 positions. The 9th number is in 10th position
        var a = new int[n];
        a[0] = 0;

     if (numElement == 0)
         return a;

    a[1] = 1;

    for (var i = 2; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Same output as before(I changed the code). The loop does not iterate at all according to the debugger for my previous code.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the refrencing. Because I'm using the method in another project in which I've added my library... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The generation of the sequence terminates too early. Change it as follows.

```
public static int[] Fibonacci(int numElement)
{
    int n = numElement - 1;
    int[] a = new int[numElement + 1];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however the code is still not working. Same output as before.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is in the wrong place and is returning the wrong type ( element currently in the loop rather than the array ), you're also making some unnecessary variables as well if you change the method to the following it should work

```
public static int[] Fibonacci(int numElement)
{
    int[] a = new int[numElement];
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;


    for (int i = 2; i < numElement; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i - 2] + a[i - 1];
    }

    return a;
}
```

You can also check out a working fiddle here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/dWZck8